# How to add class .selected dynamically to selected element here?

Tags: jquery

In this example . By clicking on thumbnail , big images is getting changed. I want to add border to selected thumbnail.

see example here http://jsfiddle.net/Qhdaz/2/

HTML

```
<div id="big-image">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1/">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/fashion/1/">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/city/1/">
</div>

<div class="small-images">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50/sports/1/">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50/fashion/1/">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50/city/1/">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.small-images a, .big-images a {display:inline-block}
.small-images a.selected {border:1px solid red}
```

Current jQuery code

```
$(function(){
    $("#big-image img:eq(0)").nextAll().hide();
    $(".small-images img").click(function(e){
        var index = $(this).index();
        $("#big-image img").eq(index).show().siblings().hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS is looking for `a` tags with the `selected` class not `img` tags:

This:

```
.small-images a.selected {border:1px solid red}
```

Should change to:

```
.small-images .selected {border:1px solid red}
```

Other than that you just need to add and remove the `selected` class on click:

```
$(function(){
    $("#big-image img:eq(0)").nextAll().hide();
    $(".small-images img").click(function(e){
        var $this = $(this),
            index = $this.index();
        $(".small-images img").removeClass('selected');
        $this.addClass('selected');
        $("#big-image img").eq(index).show().siblings().hide();
    });
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Qhdaz/6/

**UPDATED**

I would suggest optimizing the code a bit by caching the `$(".small-images img")` selection since it will be used in each `click` event handler:

```
$(function(){
    var $thumbnails = $(".small-images img");

    //this will add the `selected` class to the first thumbnail on-load
    $thumbnails.eq(0).addClass('selected');
    $("#big-image img:eq(0)").nextAll().hide();
    $thumbnails.click(function(e){

        //cache the `$(this)` selector since it will be used more than once
        var $this = $(this),
            index = $this.index();

        //remove `selected` class from all thumbnails
        $thumbnails.removeClass('selected');
        //add `selected` class to selected thumbnail
        $this.addClass('selected');

        $("#big-image img").eq(index).show().siblings().hide();
    });
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Qhdaz/12/

Here is your code optimized to run speedily:

CSS--

```
/*this will hide the full-sized images by default to take care of the flickering on-load*/
#big-image img {
    display : none;
}
```

JS--

```
$(function(){

    //cache both the thumbnails and the full-sized images so when we do work on them we don't have to wait for the performance hating selector to do it's magic
    var $thumbnails = $(".small-images img"),
        $fullsized  = $("#big-image img");

    //add `selected` class to first thumbnail
    $thumbnails.eq(0).addClass('selected');

    //show first full-sized image (no
    $fullsized.eq(0).show();

    //add `click` event handlers to all the thumbnails
    $thumbnails.click(function(e){

        //cache the `$(this)` selector since it will be used more than once
        var $this = $(this),
            index = $this.index();

        //remove the `selected` class from all thumbnails
        $thumbnails.removeClass('selected');

        //add the `selected` class to selected thumbnail
        $this.addClass('selected');

        //hide all the full-sized images and show the currently selected index
        $fullsized.hide().eq(index).show();
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Qhdaz/13/

Comment: Thanks for code. I want to do one more thing in it. on page load first images should be selected by default. then user can select other images if he want. and when user select any other image that should be selected

Comment: @JitendraVyas Just add: `$thumbnails.eq(0).addClass('selected');` to the `document.ready` event handler: http://jsfiddle.net/Qhdaz/12/

Answer (score 1):

----UPDATED VERSION----
if you don't need any animation you can use a lot more CSS.
This example shows some CSS3 styling and a short jQuery script to change the images.

http://jsfiddle.net/pixelass/hzLfV/7/

jQuery

```
$(function() {
    $(".small-images img").click(function() {
        $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
        var index = $(this).index();
        $("#big-image img.active").removeClass('active');
        $("#big-image img").eq(index).addClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    });
});
```

CSS

```
#wrapper  { 
    height:280px;
    width:420px;
    background:#fff;
    overflow:none;
}
#big-image {
    height:220px;
}
#big-image img  {
    position:absolute;
    top:5px;
    left:5px;
    display:none;
    box-shadow:0 4px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    -moz-box-shadow:0 4px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 4px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    -o-box-shadow:0 4px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}
#big-image img.active  {
    display:block;
}
.small-images {
    position:absolute;
    top:220px;
    left:5px;
    height:60px;
}
.small-images img {
    border:5px solid white;
    box-shadow:0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    -moz-box-shadow:0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    -o-box-shadow:0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    display:inline;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    margin:0 5px 0 0;
}
.small-images img.selected {
    border:5px solid #888;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="big-image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1/" class="active">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/fashion/1/">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/city/1/">
    </div>

    <div class="small-images">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50/sports/1/" class="selected">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50/fashion/1/">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50/city/1/">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm already using lots of other javascript on the page. I got 3 answer but don't which one is more optimized for speed.

Comment: your solution seems close to what I need.

Comment: my version is not optimized but it shows how to make it work and look a little nicer. for example.. calling all siblings isn't really fast if you have a lot of elements. So you could add a selected class to the top image too and then just hide the selected top image remove it's class and set the new image to selected...

Comment: @JitendraVyas To speed things up it's always a good idea to cache selections rather than creating new jQuery objects within each `click` event handler.

Comment: Just a quick note about `inline-block`. It won't be read properly by IE7 but you can add `*display:inline; zoom:1` to the end of the CSS rule to support IE7.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by the following code:

```
$(function(){
    var selected;
    $("#big-image img:eq(0)").nextAll().hide();
    $(".small-images img").click(function(e){
        var index = $(this).index();
        $("#big-image img").eq(index).show().siblings().hide();
        if (typeof selected !== 'undefined') {
            selected.removeClass('selected');
        }
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        selected = $(this);
    });
});
```

Where you have these classes:

```
.small-images a, .big-images a {display:inline-block}
.small-images .selected {border:1px solid red}
```

In the first line of the anonymous function you're defining variable where you're going to keep the current selected picture.

With the if condition you're checking whether there is already any selected thumb so if such a thumb exists you're removing it's border, adding border to the new one and making it selected.