# How to implement .selected to images in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm having some difficulty with highlighting the image of a clicked element. The selected small image thumbnail displays the larger image in another div (which I have working fine).

HTML

```
    <div id=samplepanel">
    <a href="_images/bigimage1.png"><img class="sampleclass" src="_images/smallimage1.png" width="50" height="50" ></a> 
    <a href="_images/bigimage2.png"><img class="sampleclass" src="_images/smallimage2.png" width="50" height="50" ></a>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
   #samplepanel img
   {
   display: inline-block;
   border: 2px dotted #5466DD;
   }
   #samplepanel img.selected
   {
   border: 5px solid #49E635;
   }
```

So I guess my issue is that I can't seem to get img.selected to have any effect for me.

I tried using this for help - [How to add class .selected dynamically to selected element here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8565254/how-to-add-class-selected-dynamically-to-selected-element-here) - unfortunately I haven't had any success yet.

Comment: Can you put together a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: If you use jquery, you can dynamically add the class: $('a').on('click',function(){ $(this).next('img').addClass('selected');});

Comment: [Did you look at this](http://jsfiddle.net/Qhdaz/13/)? It was the demo of one of the answers on the link in your question.

Comment: Ahh, if I can only achieve the highlighted selection with javascript / jQuery that would make sense. I wasn't sure what CSS on its own was capable of with '.selected'

Comment: well .selected would be a custom class you would need to make, I think you are thinking of the :active state (e.g. a:active), which still wouldn't achieve what you are trying to do. jQuery is the easiest solution

Answer (score 0):

If .selected isn't being dynamically added to your DOM, (as with jQuery) there is no way for CSS to select it.

However, HTML does afford a pseudo class that might be relevant to you:

```
#samplepanel a:active img{
    border: 5px solid #49E635;
}
```